# Slightly different loops in python / Minimize code

Tags: python, optimization

I just want to minify the rows of the code. I have two loops with the only difference two lines. Is it possible (functions or classes) to change the lines in each occasion? The two loops are:

```
cursor = ''
while True:
    data =  API_like_query(id,cursor)
    #more code
    for i in data['data']:
        ids_likes += i['id']+' , '
    #more code
```

and

```
cursor = ''
while True:
    data =  API_com_query(id,cursor)
    #more code
    for i in data['data']:
        ids_likes += i['from']['id']+' , '
    #more code
```

More code is the same chunk of code used. The difference is in the function call (line 3) and the different dictionary object in line 6.

Comment: Different optimization that you asked for, but is `ids_likes` *just* a string with IDs joined by ' , '? Then you should use `' , '.join(lst)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function quite easily:

```
def do_stuff(api_func, get_data_func):
    cursor = ''
    while True:
        data = api_func(id, cursor)
        #more code
        for i in data['data']:
            ids_likes += get_data_func(i) + ', '
        #more code
```

Then the first loop can be reproduced with:

```
do_stuff(API_like_query, lambda i: i['id'])
```

And the second one:

```
do_stuff(API_come_query, lambda i: i['from']['id'])
```

Functions are made to divide code into smaller, more easily testable and reusable pieces, so it seems appropriate in this case.

Comment: Even neater than lambdas would probably be to use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to construct the getter functions. Other than that, this is by far the cleanest approach in my opinion.

Comment: @LukasGraf The first one can be easily replaced with `itemgetter`, but the nested access of the second case isn't easily replaced. you have to use `partial` or `lambda` anyway.

Comment: Indeed, just realized that when playing around with them myself. +1 for mentioning [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), didn't know about that! :)

Answer (score 0):

`joinedquery=izip(API_like_query(id,cursor),API_com_query(id,cursor))` if query length the same. then `for i1,i2 in joinedquery:`

Answer (score -1):

You can put everything into a function with an argument which way to use:

```
def do_something(which_query):
    cursor = ''
    while True:
        if which_query == 1:
            data =  API_like_query(id,cursor)
        elif which_query == 2:
            data =  API_com_query(id,cursor)
        #code
        for i in data['data']:
            if which_query == 1:
                ids_likes += i['id']+' , '
            elif which_query == 2:
                ids_likes += i['from']['id']+' , '
        #more code
```

But the additional if's only make the code shorter not faster!